# Crawler4j missing outgoing links?

Tags: crawler4j

I'm trying to crawl the Apache Mailing Lists to get all the archived messages using Crawler4j. I provided a seed URL and am trying to get links to the other messages. However, it seems to not be extracting all the links.

Following is the HTML of my seed page (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3CCAOG_4QZ-yyrcwTpRu-8eu6VoUoM3%3DAo_J8Linhpnc%2B6y7tOcxg%40mail.gmail.com%3E):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Re: some healthy broker disappear from zookeeper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/archives/style.css" />
 </head>

 <body id="archives">
  <h1>kafka-users mailing list archives</h1>

  <h5>
<a href="http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/" title="Back to the archives depot">Site index</a> &middot; <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users" title="Back to the list index">List index</a></h5>  <table class="static" id="msgview">
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="title">Message view</th>
    <th class="nav"><a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAFbh0Q1uJGxQiH15a7xS+pCwq+Jft9yKhb66t_C78UrMX338mQ@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Previous by date">&laquo;</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/date" title="View messages sorted by date">Date</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAA+BczTexvtqSK+nmauvj37vhTF31awzeegpWdk6eZ-+LaGTVw@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Next by date">&raquo;</a> &middot; <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAPkvrnkTEtfFhYnCMj=xMs58pFU1sy-9sJuJ6e19mGVVipRg0A@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Previous by thread">&laquo;</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/thread" title="View messages sorted by thread">Thread</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAA+BczS5JOCA+QpgLU+tXeG=Ke_MXxiG_PinMt0YDxGBtz5nPg@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Next by thread">&raquo;</a></th>
   </tr>
   </thead>

   <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th class="title"><a href="#archives">Top</a></th>
    <th class="nav"><a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAFbh0Q1uJGxQiH15a7xS+pCwq+Jft9yKhb66t_C78UrMX338mQ@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Previous by date">&laquo;</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/date" title="View messages sorted by date">Date</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAA+BczTexvtqSK+nmauvj37vhTF31awzeegpWdk6eZ-+LaGTVw@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Next by date">&raquo;</a> &middot; <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAPkvrnkTEtfFhYnCMj=xMs58pFU1sy-9sJuJ6e19mGVVipRg0A@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Previous by thread">&laquo;</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/thread" title="View messages sorted by thread">Thread</a> <a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAA+BczS5JOCA+QpgLU+tXeG=Ke_MXxiG_PinMt0YDxGBtz5nPg@mail.gmail.com%3e" title="Next by thread">&raquo;</a></th>
   </tr>
   </tfoot>

   <tbody>
   <tr class="from">
    <td class="left">From</td>
    <td class="right">Neha Narkhede &lt;neha.narkh...@gmail.com&gt;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="subject">
    <td class="left">Subject</td>
    <td class="right">Re: some healthy broker disappear from zookeeper</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="date">
    <td class="left">Date</td>
    <td class="right">Tue, 20 Nov 2012 19:01:56 GMT</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="contents"><td colspan="2"><pre>
zookeeper server version is 3.3.3 is pretty buggy and has known
session expiration and unexpected ephemeral node deletion bugs.
Please upgrade to 3.3.4 and retry.

Thanks,
Neha

On Tue, Nov 20, 2012 at 10:42 AM, Xiaoyu Wang &lt;xwang@rocketfuel.com&gt; wrote:
&gt; Hello everybody,
&gt;
&gt; We have run into this problem a few times in the past week. The symptom is
&gt; some broker disappear from zookeeper. The broker appears to be healthy.
&gt; After that, producers start producing lots of ZK producer cache stale log
&gt; and stop making any progress.
&gt;  "logger.info("Try #" + numRetries + " ZK producer cache is stale.
&gt; Refreshing it by reading from ZK again")"
&gt;
&gt; We are running kafka 0.7.1 and the zookeeper server version is 3.3.3.
&gt;
&gt; The missing broker will show up in zookeeper after we restart it. My
&gt; question is
&gt;
&gt;    1. Did anyone encounter the same problem? how did you fix it?
&gt;    2. Why producer is not making any progress? Can we make the producer
&gt;    work with those brokers that are listed in zookeeper.
&gt;
&gt;
&gt; Thanks,
&gt;
&gt; -Xiaoyu

</pre></td></tr>
   <tr class="mime">
    <td class="left">Mime</td>
    <td class="right">
<ul>
<li><a rel="nofollow" href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/raw/%3cCAOG_4QZ-yyrcwTpRu-8eu6VoUoM3=Ao_J8Linhpnc+6y7tOcxg@mail.gmail.com%3e/">Unnamed text/plain</a> (inline, None, 1037 bytes)</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
   <tr class="raw">
    <td class="left"></td>
    <td class="right"><a href="/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/raw/%3cCAOG_4QZ-yyrcwTpRu-8eu6VoUoM3=Ao_J8Linhpnc+6y7tOcxg@mail.gmail.com%3e" rel="nofollow">View raw message</a></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

These are the outgoing URLs as identified by Crawler4j.

```
http://mail-archives.apache.org/archives/style.css
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/date
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/thread
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3CCAOG_4QZ-yyrcwTpRu-8eu6VoUoM3%3DAo_J8Linhpnc%2B6y7tOcxg%40mail.gmail.com%3E
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/date
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/thread
```

However, the URLs that I'm interested in are missing.

```
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAFbh0Q1uJGxQiH15a7xS+pCwq+Jft9yKhb66t_C78UrMX338mQ@mail.gmail.com%3e
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAA+BczTexvtqSK+nmauvj37vhTF31awzeegpWdk6eZ-+LaGTVw@mail.gmail.com%3e
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAPkvrnkTEtfFhYnCMj=xMs58pFU1sy-9sJuJ6e19mGVVipRg0A@mail.gmail.com%3e
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCAA+BczS5JOCA+QpgLU+tXeG=Ke_MXxiG_PinMt0YDxGBtz5nPg@mail.gmail.com%3e
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get Crawler4j to extract the URLs I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please tell me you have noticed there are direct links for downloading [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) files for mailing lists. In your case, just wget this, no crawler needed:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox

Answer (score 0):

You are probably giving the wrong seed page.
I think your seed page should be:

[http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod%5fmbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/thread)

and then use

```
public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
    String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
    return (!FILTERS.matcher(href).matches() && href.contains("http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201211.mbox/%3cCA"));
}
```

I hope that helps.